# Basename not working properly

Tags: react-router

I'm attempting to use a basename with react-router as documented [on the react-router docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#examples).  This is due to [base href](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3387) being deprecated.

Here is what I have now:

```html
import { Route, Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

var history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: '/subdirectory'
});

render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <Route path='next' component={Next} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When I go to `http://the-url.com/subdirectory` the page loads as expected (rendering the `App` component).  However, when going to `http://the-url.com/subdirectory/next`, I get a 404 error.  My nginx config is:

```
location /subdirectory {
  alias /path/to/index.html;
  index index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /path/to/index.html;
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this??

Comment: Any solution for this yet?

Answer (score 9):

#### Here is how I managed to get it to work

Set Router basename to your subdirectory like this

`<Router basename="/subdirectory">`

If you used create-react-app and are building using npm run build you need to set homepage in **package.json** for the paths to be correct in the production build

`homepage: "{http://www.the-url.com/subdirectory}"`

For the nginx config, let's assume your index.html is under `/path/to/subdirectory/index.html`. Then the following should work

```
location /subdirectory {
    root /path/to;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /subdirectory/index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by using:

```
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

const history = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({
    basename: '/',
})

<Router history={history}>
```

I think the issue was different versions of the `history` package. `react-router@2.2.4` uses `history@2.1.2`, while `history` is already at `4.5.1`.
So make sure you install the correct version of the `history` package.

Comment: it works fine on development but still fails in production though

Answer (score 4):

**Using BrowserRouter**

helpers/history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

index.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import history from "helpers/history";
.....

<Router history={history} basename={'/app'}>  
...
</Router>
```

**Using Router**

helpers/history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory({ basename: '/app' });
```

index.js

```
import {Router} from "react-router-dom";
import history from "helpers/history";
....

<Router history={history}>  
...
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is too sad that react documentation does not specify anything regarding basename in react router v6. however, I tried something and it worked. please find below solution. cheers!

```
    <HashRouter> 
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/app'> {/* put url base here and nest children routes */}
            <Route path='path1' element={ <Somecomponent1 /> } />
            <Route path='path2' element={ <Somecomponent2 /> } />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/app/path1" />}  /> {/* navigate to default route if no url matched */}
    </Routes>
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me: 
1) code files got loaded alright, but 2) I got a blank page, and this in the log: 
```react-dom.production.min.js:186 Error
    at i (router.ts:5:20)
    at k (components.tsx:147:3)
    at ko (react-dom.production.min.js:166:137)
   [...]
    at rs (react-dom.production.min.js:267:429)
    at S (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)```
(instead, I switched back to non-nested routes, then it worked again)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<HashRouter> 
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/app'> {/* put url base here and nest children routes */}
            <Route path='path1' element={ <Somecomponent1 /> } />
            <Route path='path2' element={ <Somecomponent2 /> } />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/app/path1" />}  /> {/* navigate to default route if no url matched */}
    </Routes>
</HashRouter>
```

I was struggling this issue from 2 days approx. This article was very helpful for me.